# Find bottom of a column in Excel using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a script that will extract the contents of a column in an Excel spreadsheet. Since I don't know how many rows will have data, I need to be able to find the end of the column in the course of the script.

In VBA, I would use something like

```
sht.Range(sht.Cells(row, col), sht.Cells(row, col)).End(xlDown).row
```

When I tried using that line in the VBScript file (I knew it probably wouldn't work, but I was hoping for some good luck), a message came back saying that 'xlDown' is undefined. I could easily create an Excel macro to do this, but I want the program to run without having to alter the original spreadsheet.

Here's part of my current script where I define the Excel objects

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wkbk = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(path)
'xlapp.Visible = False
Set sht = wkbk.Sheets(sheetname)
Set myfile = fso.OpenTextFile(txtfile, 2, True)
lrow = sht.Range(sht.Cells(row, col), sht.Cells(row, col)).End(xlDown).row
```

path, sheetname, and txtfile are previously defined strings, and row and col are previously defined integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlDown` is actually a constant. It's value is -4121 as mentioned [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221100(v=office.11).aspx#Anchor_50).
So try something like,

```
const xlDown = -4121
lrow  = sht.Range(sht.Cells(row, col), sht.Cells(row, col)).End(xlDown).row
```

OR you can make use of `xlUp` also in the following code to get the rowcount of a column say Column A:

```
const xlUp = -4162
lrow = sht.Range("A" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Glad that it worked. Here is simple one which will give you the count of rows in the used range for sheet *sht*

```
lrow = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```